# Gateway response not working in subdirectory wordpress install

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway

I have created a plugin that accepts payments for a specific gateway. When used in root dir Wordpress install it gives no problems.

When I try to use it in a Wordpress installation placed in a subdirectory it fails.

In root installation the form works properly and the user is redirected to the gateway page.

Once the user completes the payment, the gateway sends a POST request with the transaction results, it is intercepted by my script which does the logic and echoes a redirect command

```
REDIRECT=urlToThankYouPage?data=encodeddatahere
```

The gateway then redirects the user to the thank you page and according to the values in the data property it displays the relevant message.

Now the mystery begins... 
The site in the subdirectory works fine, but the plugin doesnt. It seems like the gateway is not doing the post request.

It looks like a simple get request as the user ends up on the callback url and the redirect command is printed out on screen. $_POST is empty, and the server does not do the redirect as if it was not expecting any response.

I could write all or parts of the script but it seems useless as the plugin works perfectly on top level installation.

May it be some certificate problem?

Any help appeciated

**EDIT**
The following code captures the gatway callback and echoes the response

```
global $constrivPayer_options;

if(isset($_GET["constrivPayer-api"]) && $_GET["constrivPayer-api"] == "Gateway_ConsTriv") {

   if (($_POST["result"]=="CAPTURED" || $_POST["result"]=="APPROVED")) {

     if (md5($_POST["udf2"].CONSTRIVPAYER_MD5.get_option('siteurl')) === $_POST["udf1"]) {

       $paymentData = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST["udf4"]), true);

       $message = "1&amount=".$paymentData["amount"]."&id=".$paymentData["payment_id"];  

     } else {

       $message = "2";

     }

   } else if (array_key_exists("Error", $_POST)) {

     $message = "3";

   } else {

     $message = "4";

   }

   $pageUrl = $constrivPayer_options["page_url"];

   $redirect = "REDIRECT=".$pageUrl."?transaction_result&transaction_message=".$message;

   echo $redirect;

   exit;

}
```

Comment: Please share code that sends request and redirect link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the end was that the callback pointed at the base url of the site. Simply setting any url beyond root as callback solved the problem. siteurl/randomanything

Immense headache for a dumb solution.